# Comma separated regex for large numbers max digits before decimal 7

Tags: regex

Can anyone please help me by modifying the below regex so it matches the pattern
1,333,333.00 as of now I have tried and it accepts 111,333,333.00

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3}){0,2}(\.\d{2})?$
```

The modified pattern should not accept "111,333,333.00"

Comment: Are you saying you want it to *not* accept "111,333,333.00"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it should not accept "111,333,333.00"

Comment: replace `[0-9]{1,3}` with `[0-9]{1}`?

Comment: @StefanZivkovic then it stops accepting 33,333.00 this also

Answer (score 1):

This regex pattern :

```
^(?=(?:,?\d){1,7}(?:\.|$))\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}){0,2}(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

Or this version without backslashes :

```
^(?=(?:,?[0-9]){1,7}(?:[.]|$))[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3}){0,2}(?:[.][0-9]{2})?$
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/g25I3r/1)

Will match the following strings:

```
1,123,123.00
123,123.00
12,123.00
1,123,123
1.00
1
```

But won't match :

```
123,123,123.00
12,123,123.00
```

> `^` : start of the line or string
> `(?=(?:,?\d){1,7}(?:\.|$))` : positive lookahead for 1 to 7 digits before the dot or end of the line/string
> `\d{1,3}` : 1 to 3 digits
> `(?:,\d{3}){0,2}` : 0 to 2 groups of a comma with 3 digits
> `(?:\.\d{2})?` : optional dot with 2 digits
> `$` : end of the line or string

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Just one thing can it also accept 111,333.00 as it will be a valid case for #,###,###.00 pattern
I mean what should i change here for the above case

Comment: Oi, that's indeed a tricky one. So not `123,123,123.00`, but still `12,123,123.00` or `123,123.00`

Comment: only 123,123.00 before decimal just want 7 digits and after decimal 2 digits.

Comment: @N.M See update. I've added a lookahead that check for max 7 digits before the decimal.